# How do I pass Hashmap list of values of type double into algorithm that combines values of type int

Tags: java, merge, intervals

I have the following code the iterates over billions of rows of data in a bigdata store and uses a hashmap to store the values in the appropriate keys.  The values are of type "double".

```
 final Map<Double, List<StartEndF>> channelmap = new HashMap<>();
 List<StartEndF> xValues = null;

                // Create Channel Power Buckets
                for(; channel <= channel_end; channel+=increment ){ 
                    //Initial Bucket
                    while((start_frequency >= channel) && (start_frequency < (channel + increment))){
                        cp.add(new ChannelPower(channel, power));

                        xValues = channelmap.get(channel);
                        if(xValues == null){
                        xValues = new ArrayList<>();
                        channelmap.put(channel, xValues);
                        }
                        xValues.add(new StartEndF(start_time, end_time));  
                        channel+=increment;          
                    }
                    //Buckets to Accomodate for Bandwidth
                    while ((channel <= channel_end) && (channel >= start_frequency) && (start_frequency + bandwidth) >= channel){
                        cp.add(new ChannelPower(channel, power));
                        xValues = channelmap.get(channel);
                        if(xValues == null){
                        xValues = new ArrayList<>();
                        channelmap.put(channel, xValues);
                    }
                    xValues.add(new StartEndF(start_time, end_time));  
                    channel+=increment;
                    }                   
                }
```

With my Class being:

```
public class StartEndF implements Serializable {
    public StartEndF(Double start_time, Double end_time) {
        this.start_time = start_time;
        this.end_time = end_time;
    }
    Double start_time;
    Double end_time;

    public void setStart_time(Double start_time) {
        this.start_time = start_time;
    }
    public void setEnd_time(Double end_time) {
        this.end_time = end_time;
    }
    public Double getStart_time() {
        return start_time;
    }
    public Double getEnd_time() {
        return end_time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +start_time +","+end_time+"]";
    }
}
```

Based on each row of data it adds it's values to an appropriate key in a hashmap.  I need to be able to sort these values by the x of the x,y represented in the values and then consolidate/combine them when they overlap like so.

**Example:**

Original:

```
mykey=[[1E8,2E8], [7E8,9E8], [1E8,5E8], [2E8,6E8]
```

Desired After Sort:

```
mykey=[[1E8,2E8], [1E8,5E8], [2E8,6E8], [7E8,9E8]]
```

**Desired Final** will need to combine on the basis of if next results x of the x,y is greater than the y of the previous then leave alone other wise combine into previous and expand the y  if the y is greater the previous.

I believe the following code will allow me to get to my final result If I can get my hashmap list value data into a format that the following code can ingest to come up with my final result example below.  This codes uses "int" but my data is in the format of "double".  I'm not sure how to pass my list `channelmap` into this in order to be processed.

```
public class MergeRange {
    public class Range{
        public int start;
        public int end;
        public Range(int s, int e){
            start = s;
            end = e;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + start + "," + end + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {  
            if (o == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(o instanceof Range)) {
                return false;
            }
            Range c = (Range) o;
            return start == c.start && end == c.end;             
        }
    }

    //compare two range by start, used to sort list of ranges by their starts
    public class RangeComparator implements Comparator<Range> {
        public int compare(Range range1, Range range2) { 
            return Integer.compare(range1.start, range2.start);
        }
    }

    public List<Range> merge(List<Range> ranges){
        if (ranges.size() < 2){
            return ranges;
        }

        ranges.sort(new RangeComparator());
        List<Range> result = new ArrayList<Range>();
        result.add(ranges.get(0));

        for (int i = 1; i < ranges.size(); i++){
            Range lastAdded = result.get(result.size() - 1);
            result.remove(result.size() - 1);
            List<Range> newRanges = merge(lastAdded, ranges.get(i));
            result.addAll(newRanges);           
        }

        return result;

    }
    //merge two ranges where range1.start <= range2.start
    private List<Range> merge(Range range1, Range range2){
        Assert.assertTrue(range1.start <= range2.start);

        if (range1.end < range2.start){
            return Arrays.asList(range1, range2);
        } else{
            Range result = new Range(range1.start, Math.max(range1.end, range2.end));
            return Arrays.asList(result);
        }
    }

}
```

**Final Result Desired:**

```
mykey=[[1E8,6E8], [7E8,9E8]]
```

Im looking for suggestions on how to accomplish this since my data is in the form of a hashmap arraylist of type double and not an array aslist of type int.

Comment: This is *merging intervals*. There's an explanation here:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a `HashMap` can't be sorted. You'll probably looking at a `TreeMap`, which you can than sort by using a `Collections.sort` and overriding the `compareTo` method. [Here is a similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to overlap intervals efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313374/how-to-overlap-intervals-efficiently)

Comment: @user1717259  That is similar but my scenario requires Java as opposed to python.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `TreeMap` uses its own comparator to sort on insert. `Collections.sort` won't work since it's not a collections, implementing `Comparable` is not required.

Comment: @mithrix you should be able to adapt the logic in both links he posted to Java. Both contain an outlined algorithm anyways which is independent of the language used.

Comment: @Thomas thank you I apologize i clarified my question.  I have an algorithm that can get my final result but Im not sure how to use it with a hashmap as opposed to an ArrayList

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand the values in your hashmap. What should be merged? Different keys or the objects in the value lists? If the keys, how would you do that if they're only scalar values? If the value lists then where's the difference?

Comment: @Thomas  The values of each key are the ones that need to be combined/consolidated as exampled above for the key mykey.

Comment: I don't get the question then. You have an algorithm that operates on lists and your map values are lists. Just replace `Range` with `StartEndF` and use the same algorithm.

Comment: @Thomas my algorithm requires the lists to be sorted my hashmap values aren't sorted.

Comment: You can always sort the lists either when adding new values (maybe even merge then already) or later in a separate run. For the latter just iterate over the `values()` collection (which should be a `Collection<List<StartEndF>>`) and sort and merge each of the lists.

Comment: As a side note, since you say you're iterating over millions of values: don't use `if(containsKey(x) { get(x) }`  but rather use ` y = get(x); if( y == null )`. You'll save a lookup each time since `containsKey(x)` will do the same as `get(x)` and just return `node != null` instead of `node.value`.