# What would be the more efficient to find interesection in time

Tags: python, algorithm, time

Imagine two passages with that are represented with seconds of speaking in tuples. Example, speaking between the 566th second and 579th.

## Old example

```
passage1 = (566,579),(573,583.33)
passage2 = (574,579.21),(614,620)
```

=> intersection (574,579.21)

## New example

```
passage1 = (566,579),(570,590)
passage2 = (572,575),(577,620)
```

=> intersection (572,575) (577,590)

What would be the most efficient way to find the intersection between these segments? How can I represent time in python ? I am open to every idea since I haven't found any way how to represent it and make the calculations.

Comment: It seems that you've asked `two` questions here. Which one comes first?

Comment: Ou sorry, you are right. Intersection would be great. Union I can find it later if I have a good beggining on the intersection. Thank you for poiting it out @DanielHao

Comment: NP. Did you try to look into `set` for your possible solutions?  It should help. It's helpful to provide some expected outputs using your inputs.

Comment: set is one option, it has in build options. Are you suggesting that it is better to create sets of floats between, those values ? I don't see any other way using set, can you please clarify @DanielHao

Comment: Are you looking at intersections between two time periods e.g. between 566-579 and 573-583.33? E.g. a function `intersection(566, 579, 573, 583.33)` which would return `573, 579`? Or between multiple periods (there could be multiple intersections with some or all of them)?

Comment: The last one multiple periods. passage1 or passsage2 can also not be overlapping (exemple: passage1 = (566,579),(580,583.33)) => there is a blanc of 1 seconds. It shouldn't appear in the global intersection. The interesection that I am searching is the between passage1 and passage2 @Stuart

Comment: So what would your output be for the given example?

Comment: @Stuart I added one more new example. I hope it can ben more clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to overlap intervals efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313374/how-to-overlap-intervals-efficiently)

Answer (score 0):

First, sort the intervals within each passage to make sure they are in order of start time, and merge any overlapping intervals within each passage.

```
passage1 = (566,579),(573,583.33)
passage2 = (574,579.21),(614,620)       
passage3 = (566,579),(570,590)
passage4 = (572,575),(577,620)

def merge_overlapping_intervals(intervals):
    intervals = iter(sorted(intervals))
    start, end = next(intervals)
    for next_start, next_end in intervals:
        if next_start <= end <= next_end:
            end = next_end
        else:
            yield start, end
            start = next_start
            end = next_end
    yield start, end

print(list(merge_overlapping_intervals(passage1)))   # 566, 583.33
```

Then, find all overlaps between intervals in passage 1 with intervals in passage 2:

```
def interval_overlaps(intervals1, intervals2):
    """ Yield all overlaps of intervals in sequence intervals1 with intervals in sequence intervals2 """
    for start1, end1 in merge_overlapping_intervals(intervals1):
        for start2, end2 in merge_overlapping_intervals(intervals2):
            if end1 > start2 and end2 > start1:
                yield max(start1, start2), min(end1, end2)

print(list(interval_overlaps(passage1, passage2)))   # [(574, 579.21)]
print(list(interval_overlaps(passage3, passage4)))   # [(572, 575), (577, 590)]
```

Equivalently, you could identify all overlaps first, and *then* sort them and merge any overlapping overlaps.

Because of the nested loop, the time-efficiency of this is O(nm) where n and m are the number of segments in each passage. A more time-efficient algorithm for identifying overlaps should be possible, given that the passages are sorted, but would require a bit more thought to write, and I imagine may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Determining if two segments intersect is quite easy.  If the end of either is before the start of the other, they **don't** intersect.

Once you know they intersect, the intersection itself is trivial to determine - it's the later of the two start times and the earlier of the two end times.  Note that this could result in a zero length segment.

Now you could simply go through each of the segments in passage1 and check against all of the segments in passage2.  But that would be a slow O(n²) algorithm (assuming both sequences are of the same length n), and you're interested in efficiency.

Since you say in the comments that the segments in each sequence will be non-overlapping, we can use that information to find a more efficient algorithm.  We can generate a sorted timeline of start and stop events for each passage, and the periods when you have a start and stop for both represent an intersection.  Unfortunately the example data you gave in the question does not meet the constraint, so I'm not sure this will work.

Edit: I see you've changed the example to meet the constraint, so now it actually works.  I held off posting this because of that problem.

```
def intersections(seq1, seq2):
    events = sorted([(s, False, 0) for s,e in seq1] +
            [(e, True, 0) for s,e in seq1] +
            [(s, False, 1) for s,e in seq2] +
            [(e, True, 1) for s,e in seq2])
    starts = [None, None]
    for time, end_flag, seq_num in events:
        if end_flag:
            if (starts[0] is not None) and (starts[1] is not None):
                yield max(starts), time
            starts[seq_num] = None
        else:
            starts[seq_num] = time

>>> for s,e in intersections(passage1, passage2):
    print(s, e)

572 575
577 579
```